# How do I achieve this particular hover effect?

Tags: css, hover, transition

I am trying to replicate [this](https://i.gyazo.com/0507b88b888639e7f3d5b3e0acacaef4.gif) hover effect but I'm even sure where to start to be honest.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png"> 
            </a>
          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="img/portfolio/game.png"> 
            </a>
          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="img/portfolio/circus.png"> 
            </a>
    </div>
```

CSS: (all I have)

```css
#portfolio .portfolio-item {
  background-color: #18BC9C;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item:hover {

}
```

I don't even know where to begin. I think I need to fix something with the z-index and opacity but I don't know where to adjust it, and I'm also not sure where to put the transition effect. Everything I've tried has not worked so if someone could show me how to achieve that hover effect from a clean slate that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to create an overlay. Just use [`opacity: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) to hide it, and show it on hover: `opacity: 0.6;`. As transition you can use: `transition: opacity ease .5s;`.

This way, you can create an color overlay over every image (would not be possible with only using background on the parent element). To create the magnifying glass, you can either use a `<span>` inside the `<a>` tag, or the other pseudo element `::before`.

```css
.portfolio-item a {
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio-item a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #457647;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease .5s;
}
.portfolio-item a:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x100/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x100/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x100/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you have to use vendor prefixes for older browsers. Also make sure that your markup is valid - a closing div tag was missing.

Comment: Again, your explanation makes sense to me, but when I try to execute this it doesn't work. You're even using the thumbnail class like myself and it's working without issue. How come you're targeting the link, and not the image element?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Which browser? Is my example abover working for you?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. Nothing changes when I hover over the images. The only thing that happens is the border turns slightly blue, and that's due to the thumbnail class in bootstrap. I am using modern version of Google Chrome on Windows 10.

Yes, your above example is working, and it's exactly what I'd like to apply to my images, only a slightly different color. I copied your code to my CSS, edited the color, saved, refreshed in chrome and nothing has changed at all. You explination makes sense to me, but for some reason there are no changes after saving and refreshing

Comment: you're right. It was a missing div tag that I some how overlooked. Thank you for your help Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this will get you started. First create an overlay opacity 0, then write a little jQuery so that on hover a class is applied opacity 1 with an rgba (rgb with opacity) and a css transition.

See the code for more, and run with this if you like I've separated the overlay from the image so you have control of them both:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '.portfolio-item' )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $( this ).find( '.overlay' ).addClass( 'show' );
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $( this ).find( '.overlay' ).removeClass( 'show' );
  });
});
```

```css
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
  }

img {
width: 100%; 
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(145,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in opacity;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease-in opacity;
    transition: .3s ease-in opacity;
  }

.overlay.show {
opacity: 1;
}

.overlay.show:after {
  content: 'x'; 
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"> 
            </a>
          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
             <div class="overlay"></div>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"> 
            </a>
          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
             <div class="overlay"></div>
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"> 
            </a>
    </div>
```